# Default culture-bases redirect in razor view engine in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization, seo

We've used a custom view engine that respects the following internationalized views naming:

Index.cshtml
Index.en.cshtml
Index.de.cshtml 
etc..

Now I am rewriting the view engine to include other new features of MVC 5. But, I'd like the web sites to be more SEO friendly this time.
Simple feature I need, is when I have a custom setting in a backend, that states that English cultured (via browser headers) users should be automatically redirected to www.mysite.com/en/
When user arrives accepting german - it is redirected to www.mysite.com/de/

Where is it best to put the redirect? In the view engine code, global.asax, etc?

Comment: could you please show your razor view engine code, i'm try to do same localized engine